# Access a JSON value dynamically from a provided variable

Tags: jquery, json

I would like to access the val['fg'] from a JSON array I have available. What I need to use the variable 'partySelected' in place of fg to access the value. Does that make sense? The each JSON array has a name which I am matching and then it needs to find a value based on value provided.

```
$.each(heatmapData.finalData, function(key, val) {
        if (val.Constituency == place) {

            console.log(partySelected);
            var heat = val['fg']+" = "+val.Constituency;
            console.log(heat)
        }

    });
```

I know the `val['fg']+" = "+val.Constituency;` bit works from the console.log that I'm seeing. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer:

```
val[partySelected]+" = "+val.Constituency;
```

this works.